# How to develop combin charts of column and line with mutiple components in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

[image: highcharts]
I am struggling for the develop  of combine charts  of line and column with multiple components in highcharts.
Here each component has different x-axis values.Please help me out

thanks in advance

Generally mine exact question is ........................

first component:componentA

```
 var y1-axis: [
            {
                "name" : "3D",
                "type" : "line",
                "data" : ["0","0","0"]

            },

            {
                "name" : "3C",
                "type" : "line",
                "data" : ["0","0","0"]
            },

            {
                "name" : "3B-NDT",
                "type" : "line",
                "data" : ["0","0","0"]
            },
            {
                "name" : "3B",
                "type" : "line",
                "data" : ["0","0","0"]
            }]


 var x1-axis : [
            {
                "name" : "jobDescription",
                "type" : "",
                "data"  : ["7799","1046","1112"]

            }

         ]
```

Second component: componentB

```
 var y2-axis: [
            {
                "name" : "3D",
                "type" : "column",
                "data" : ["0","7.98","0"]

            },

            {
                "name" : "3C",
                "type" : "column",
                "data" : ["0","1.82","6.64"]
            },

            {
                "name" : "3B-NDT",
                "type" : "column",
                "data" : ["0","48.12","37.87"]
            }]

 var x2-axis : [
            {
                "name" : "jobDescription1",
                "type" : "",
                "data"  : ["7801", "1111", "1147"]

            }

         ]
```

hw can design column chart with two components in single chart like

pls find the attached image  of highchart

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

In general something like this is possible by using `xAxis.left` and `xAxis.width` like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/45v24/4/

However, it looks like tooltip has bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2062).